# How to add custom tabs at product detailed page?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

How can i add custom tabs at product detailed page as description tab?

Comment: thy this extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/free-products-tabs-extension-for-magento.html

Comment: Why you repeating same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these lines to my theme's ***local.xml*** file and created a corresponding ***videos.phtml*** file for it

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.videos" as="videos" template="catalog/product/view/videos.phtml" after="additional">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Videos</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>  
</catalog_product_view>
```